# cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Error occurred when trying to add qresult. Anyone can please advise / guide how to fix / amend my code? thanks
cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>

```
public class SystemAccessList
{
     public SystemAccess SystemAccess { get; set; }

     public List<SystemAccess> SystemAccessList { get; set; }

     SystemDbContext db;

 public void setDbContext(PALMSConfigDbContext _db)
    {
        db = _db;
    }

  public SystemAccessList GetAccessList(SystemAccessList systemAccessList)
  {

    var qresult = db.tbl_SystemAccessList
            .GroupBy(g => g.ClassID)
            .AsEnumerable().Select(c =>
            {
                var rr = new ResultRow { Class = c.Key };
                foreach (var r in db.tbl_SystemAccessList.GroupBy(gg => gg.StudentID))
                {
                    rr.Student[r.Key] = "N";
                }
                foreach (var r in c.Where(w => w.ClassID == c.Key))
                {
                    rr.Student[r.StudentID] = "Y";
                }
                return rr;
            }).ToList();

    systemAccessList.SystemAccessList.AddRange(qresult);
    return systemAccessList;
}

class ResultRow
{
    public ResultRow()
    {
        Student = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public string Class { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, string> Student { get; set; }

    public string GetHeader()
    {
        return Student.Aggregate("Class", (current, s) => current + "|" + s.Key);
    }

    public string GetSolidRow()
    {
        return Student.Aggregate(Class, (current, s) => current + "|" + s.Value);
    }
    }

  public class SystemAccess
   {
       [Key]
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string ClassID { get; set; }
       public string StudentID { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: what type is SystemAccessList?

Comment: Possible your qresult returned other new list than SystemAccessList, requires explicit cast to convert qresult's type into SystemAccessList and add results in its range.

Comment: public List<>....may i know how to convert it ?

Comment: `List<>` of what type?

Comment: this is how i declare the list public List<SystemAccess> SystemAccessList { get; set; }. My qresult will have dynamic number of column depends on how many student i have.

Comment: Now it comes to question how  `SystemAccess`  defined? Can you edit the code and include `SystemAccess` class as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your `qresult` will be of type `List<ResultRow>` because of the `Select` you have there. A `List<ResultRow>` is also an `IEnumerable<ResultRow>` which (when I assume `ResultRow` is a reference type (`class`)) by turn is an `IEnumerable<Xxx>` for any `Xxx` that is either a base class of `ResultRow`, or an interface that `ResultRow` implements.

Your `SystemAccessList` is of type `List<SystemAccess>` whose `AddRange` method than requires an `IEnumerable<SystemAccess>`.

So all would be fine if a `ResultRow` *were* a `SystemAccess` (by inheritance). But it is not. So you should get a message at compile-time saying the `List<ResultRow>` is not an `IEnumerable<SystemAccess>`.

Comment: yes, i got error converting to IEnumerable<>. May i know how to fixed it?